# macOS terminal corruption with larger font in Vim (the line I am editing is not the line being displayed!)

Tags: terminal, vim, fonts

I'm experiencing terminal corruption on macOS in `vim`, but only with larger fonts. (FWIW, this also appears to happen on macOS when using vim ssh'ed into another machine.)

This occurs as the text being displayed not matching where there text cursor is positioned. So I'll edit, save, and realize I edited a different line than was presented to me.

Initially, I was using `vim` on Terminal because I was experiencing terminal corruption with iTerm. When I made the fonts larger on Terminal, I experience so much vim terminal corruption that I cannot edit.

[Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21461/how-to-avoid-screen-corruption?newreg=1dbdc86b697b49dd8b46a6e63f9e8369) is a workaround that used to work, but now doesn't. I still get a terminal where the cursor is not at the displayed line.

This issue is happening on macOS 12.6 (Monterey) on a system with an M2 chip.

This doesn't occur with `less` or `nano`, and doesn't occur with `vim` when the file being edited is smaller than the window.

Comment: Please explain what “terminal corruption” means to you? The [linked post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21461/how-to-avoid-screen-corruption) mentions visual/creen corruption. But it isn’t clear from your question what exactly is being “corrupted” here.

Comment: When I search for something in vim, it displays incorrectly. Whereas if I page forward, you can see the text it was intending to match but displaying wrong. Here is a screencast: https://imgur.com/a/HSxMtjE

Comment: Note that this doesn't happen in tmux sessions through ssh

Comment: Looks like a graphical error to me. Possibly, some poor interaction between VIM and the graphics system. How old is your computer? Is it fully updated? Are any other applications showing odd display issues?

Comment: This is a MacBook Air (M2, 2022). Fully updated. No other display issues.